# Корректное отображение значений на оси графика

Tags: python, matplotlib, график

Моя задача - решить систему дифференциальных уравнений и построить график.
Использую Jupyter Notebook.
В результате интегрирования у меня появился некоторый массив чисел. Все значения элементов колеблются возле 1.0 и изменения происходят в районе 10^-7. 
По этому массиву был построен график с помощью этого кода.

```
from matplotlib import mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
plt.plot(t,A1, 'r',linewidth=0.7)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('a1')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

В итоге, был получен этот график.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не совсем понимаю, что написано сверху рамки графика и почему на оси а1 значения отображаются именно так. Ведь ожидалось, что будут написаны 1.0000000 + изменение. Как здесь на оси x1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите исправить некорректное отображение чисел на оси а1, пожалуйста

UPD: при применении команды перед прорисовкой графика

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

ситуация меняется, но не до конца[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте перед отрисовкой добавить `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')`

Comment: @strawdog, с нулями проблема решилась. Но 1 осталась наверху.

Comment: нужно отключить offset - я добавил ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вариант по аналогии с вашим:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

a = list(range(5))
random.shuffle(a)

b = np.linspace(1, 1.0000005, 5)

plt.plot(a, b)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исправленный вариант:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

a = list(range(5))
random.shuffle(a)

b = np.linspace(1, 1.0000005, 5)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y', useOffset=False)
plt.plot(a, b)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]